# Prove that given 4 elements from A, two of them must coincide in at least 2 places.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Let A be the set of all 8-digit numbers in base 3 (so they are written
>   with the digits 0,1,2 only), including those with leading zeroes such
>   as 00120010. Prove that given 4 elements from A, two of them must
>   coincide in at least 2 places.

I know that I have to use the pigeon hole principle. How can I resolve the problem with this principle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your four numbers are $a,b,c,d$.  Let's suppose that the collection $a,b,c$ does not have your property (if it does, then we are done).  It follows that any two of these can coincide in at most one slot.  Let $i_{ab}$ be the slot where $a,b$ coincide (if there is one) and define $i_{bc}, i_{ac}$ similarly.  Of course some of these may not exist or there may be coincidences. In any case, there are at least $5$ slots in which $a,b,c$ cover all three possibilities. It follows that $d$ must match one of $a,b,c$ in each of the five slots.  Thus it must match one of them at least twice.

Comment: i dont get why d must match one of a, b , c in **each** of the five slots and also how you concluded  **must match one of them atleast twice** . please can you explain?

Comment: just consider the case of three columns being there that is iab ,ibc,ica exists and no two are same . explain in that case and the other case where no such column exists'

Comment: The point is that there are only three slots or fewer in which $a,b,c$  match in pairs. That means there are $5$ slots in which no two of those match, so there must be one of each digit between them. One of those must match $d$.  Now just count pigeons.  @Paracetamol

Comment: understoood thanks

Answer (score 3):

Imagine you write down the numbers in a list like this:

00112200

01220011

02001122

01201201

You have eight columns. Each of the columns has 4 entries. Entries can only be 0, 1 or 2. Therefore, in each column some entry is repeated.

If you count the pairs of numbers among those 4 numbers, there are $\binom{4}{2}=6$ pairs.

Because we have 8 columns (it could be 7 as well, this is where the pigeons come in), there are two columns, where the repeated value is repeated in the same numbers. Let me explain what I mean:

For example, let's say in the first column there is a zero in both 2nd and 4th numbers and also in the sixth column there is a two in both 2nd and 4th numbers.

This is equivalent to the fact that 2nd and 4th numbers coincide at the 1st and 6th digit.

**If that wasn't clear, in other words:** for each column write down one pair of rows with the same entry. For my example numbers it would be:

column 1 - rows 1, 2

column 2 - rows 2, 4

column 3 - rows 3, 4

etc.

There are only 6 expressions of type "rows a, b" where $1 \le a, b \le 4$. Therefore one must be repeated. This repetition of "rows a, b" means that numbers a, b coincide at at least two digits.